# How to architect an Express route that knows time of the day

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, momentjs

I am trying to create a route that functions as the following:

The mobile app will make a request: `GET /ballots/today`, which should return the ballot for "today" ONLY if the time is between 6:00pm EST - 10:00pm EST.

If the request is made before OR after that period of time, it should not return anything.

I am considering using `moment` library's `isBetween` method inside the `express` route to check if the current time is between 6:00pm and 10:00pm of that specific day.

However, the problem I have trouble understanding is how make sure the server has the correct time at all times (if that should even be a concern) as well as being agnostic to timezones.

If it matters, I am planning on deploying on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment will always use the server time when running it on express. Most cloud providers have their server time set to UTC. You will have to provide the timezone using [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Here is an example of how to achieve it.

```
//set the start and end times for today EST
const start = moment.tz("America/New_York").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " 18:00";
const end = moment.tz("America/New_York").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + " 22:00";

//convert the times to moments so we can do a compare
const startMoment = moment.tz(start, "America/New_York");
const endMoment = moment.tz(end, "America/New_York");

const isBetween = moment.tz("America/New_York").isBetween(startMoment, endMoment);

if (isBetween) {
  //return ballot
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you for the illustrative example! Just one clarification, there should not be a worry for cloud providers' servers to ever have the wrong time right?

Comment: @hopelessmuffins no, you don't have to worry about cloud providers having the wrong time. They will use internet time servers that they sync with.